# Installing rosjava android_core is missing compressed_visualization_transport_msgs

Tags: android-core, rosjava, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to install android_core as described [here](http://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/android_core/html/building.html), but

1. '/home/andreas/workspace/android_core/android_core$ ./gradlew debug'

> What went wrong:
> Execution failed for task ':android_acm_serial:updateProject'.
> A problem occurred starting command 'android'.

2. 'android_core/android_acm_serial$ gradle debug' fails at building android_honeycomb_mr2

> [javac] /home/andreas/workspace/android_core/android_honeycomb_mr2/ src/org/ros/android/view/visualization/layer/CompressedBitmapLayer.java:42:

> package compressed_visualization_transport_msgs does not exist

3. Building /home/andreas/workspace/google (as proposed [here](http://goo.gl/8OkM2)) runs successfully, while rosmake'ing it fails on several dependencies *(I though rosmake --rosdep-install should take care of this; could it be my rosmake is broken? how do I test rosmake anyway?)*

After installing lse_xsens_mti, cereal port, hector_mapping and hector_imu_attitude_to_tf manually (i.e. checkout each package and run rosmake for it) '/home/andreas/workspace/google$ rosmake' ran without failures.

Unfortunately, 'android_core/android_acm_serial$ gradle debug' still claims that 'package compressed_visualization_transport_msgs does not exist' as above.

Looking at 'rospack --list-names', there are

- (the manually installed) lse_xsens_mti, cereal_port, hector_mapping, hector_imu_attitude_to_tf
- rosjava, rosjava_tutorial_services, rosjava_messages, rosjava_bootstrap, rosjava_geometry, rosjava_actionlib, rosjava_actionlib_tutorial, rosjava_tutorial_pubsub,
- polling_input_stream
- compressed_visualization_transport_msgs
- compressed_visualization_transport
- google_handheld_slam
- hokuyo
- android_tutorial_image_transport, android_tutorial_camera, android_acm_serial, android_tutorial_hokuyo, android_tutorial_teleop, android_tutorial_pubsub, android_gingerbread, android_honeycomb_mr2
- compressed_image_transport
- ...

So what did I miss to build android_core?

Thanks in advance!

Best regards,
Andreas

@Gemini: It was something about my android setup but unrelated to ROS. Sorry I can't remember how I've solved it.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32319/installing-rosjava-android_core-is-missing-compressed_visualization_transport_msgs/) by [andreasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/1333/andreasw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2012-04-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You only need to ensure that compressed_visualization_transport_msgs is in your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH and then re-install rosjava_messages.

```
roscd rosjava_messages
../gradlew install
```

That will generate the required message dependencies and make them available to your rosjava packages.

See: http://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/rosjava_core/html/getting_started.html#messages

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2012-04-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1